# How do I wrap everything inside a TD element with a SPAN or DIV

Tags: jquery, asp.net-membership, jquery-selectors

What am I doing wrong, my html is rendered as such:

```
<td colspan="2"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_RememberMe"   
type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$RememberMe" />  
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_RememberMe">Remember me next time.  
</label></td>
```

1. I want to wrap everything inside the
   TD with a span.
2. The idea is to increase the font size of the text
   "Remember me next time."

I have this so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("input:checkbox").css("border", "none");

        //$("input:checkbox").parent().addclass("checkboxtd");

        var parentTd = $("input:checkbox").parent();
        var prevToCheckBox = $("input:checkbox").prev();

        $(prevToCheckBox).css("border", "solid 1px red"); alert(prevToCheckBox);
        alert(prevToCheckBox.html());

        var parentofParent = parentTd.parent();

        $(parentTd).prepend("<span>");
        $(parentTd).append("</span>"); //+ "</span>"

        //parentTd.before("<div class=\"checkboxtd\"></div>");
        alert(parentTd.parent().html());

        //        $("input:checkbox").css("border", "none").prepend("<span>ss");
        //        $("input:checkbox").css("border", "none").prepend("<span>ss");
        //        $("h2").prepend("<span>ss");
        //        $('h2').append("</span>"); //+ "</span>"
    });
```

**Output from alert(parentTd.parent().html());**

```
<TD colSpan=2><INPUT id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_RememberMe 
style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none" type=checkbox name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$RememberMe>  
<LABEL for=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_RememberMe>Remember me next time.
</LABEL></SPAN></TD>
```

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but important reading before you go down this path: http://davespicks.com/essays/notables.html,
http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Comment: Also, why are you using JS for this? Why not just use CSS?

Comment: Your code is very confusing. What is `prevToCheckBox` targeting? Also why are you defining `parentofParent`? If you want the `<tr>` it's easiest to use `.closest('tr')` (http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest)

Comment: I would use css, but I was referencing StackOverFlow css and was wondering how the checkbox below on this page, Notify, is styled. I could not find in http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=5290.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove these two lines:

```
$(parentTd).prepend("<span>");
$(parentTd).append("</span>"); //+ "</span>"
```

And use this line:

```
$(parentTd).wrapInner("<span></span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try manipulating the HTML directly:

```
var parentTdHTML = parentTd.html();
parentTd.html("<span>" + parentTdHTML + "</span>");
```

However, as outis said as a comment to your question, what you're doing is unnecessary. You've properly surrounded the text you wish to stylize with a `<label>`, which means you can easily change the styling via CSS:

```
label {
    font-size: 110%;
}
```